# Publish 'older' version of package?

Tags: npm

I published a `major` version of a package on npm but I am now realizing that it should've been only a `minor` update. The recently published version is `2.0.0`, before I published it was `1.3.0`. Is there a way to go back and publish version `1.4.0` now? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [npm Unpublish Policy](https://docs.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish).

If your version `2.0.0` was published less than 72 hours ago, and no other packages in the npm Public Registry depend on version `2.0.0` of your package, then consider performing the following steps:

1. Run the following command to unpublished version `2.0.0`:

   ```
   npm unpublish <package_name>@2.0.0
   ```
2. Then publish your `1.4.0` version.

Also note that in the [Considerations](https://docs.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish#considerations) section it states:

> *Once `package@version` has been used, you can never use it again. You must publish a new version even if you unpublished the old one.*

This will mean that when you do want to publish the next major update, i.e. version `2.0.0`, you are not allowed, therefore you’ll have to publish it as `2.0.1` instead.

Comment: Is there some way to "free up" v2.0.0 to re-use again? I assume not, since it might be a security issue, but I would prefer not to jump from v1.x.x to v2.0.1 if possible. Also, from https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5058 the command `npm view {package} time` shows which versions (including unpublished) are used up.